# SQL Pivot table returning NULL for non-existent child table values

Tags: sql, null, pivot, default-value

I have a typical RDMS setup where records in a main table can have optional records in a related table via a M2M join.  I'm trying to PIVOT this data but in cases where there is no relation I want to return a default value.  The join I have below is returning NULL.

```
select * 
from
(
    SELECT s.Biz_Name, la.Name AS Association, ISNULL(i.Location, 'Default') as Location
    FROM  dbo.ShopAssociations sa 
    INNER JOIN dbo.LookupAssociations la 
        ON sa.AssociationID = la.AssociationID 
    RIGHT JOIN dbo.Basic_Shop_Info s 
        ON sa.ShopID = s.ShopID 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Images i 
        ON la.ImageID = i.ImageID
) DataTable
PIVOT 
(
    min(Location) 
    for association in
        ([OnCall],[OCGuy],[ASCLogo],[ASC_OtherSt],[ASE],[AASP],[AASP_PA],
        [ASE_BlueSeal],[AAA],[AAA-B],[ASA],[ATRA],[ICAR],[CAA],[ACDelco],
        [Cert],[ASC],[BBB],[Goodyear],[Limos],[RVs],[Bosch],[NARSA],
        [DiscTire],[BigO],[Tires],[Firestone],[ASCCA],[JustTires],[ASE_Blue])
) PivotTable
```

The output looks like this:

```
BizName          OnCall     OCGuy     ASCLogo ASC_OtherSt ASE ...
"Wonderful Biz"  somevalue  somevalue NULL    somevalue   NULL
```

What I am trying to achieve is if a child record doesn't exist in INNER JOIN from Basic_Shop_Info to ShopAssociations that we get "Default" instead of NULL.  I've tried ISNULL(), Coalesce() and even a CASE statement, all with the same results.

Comment: Here's a hack, in the top SELECT I added each pivoted column, e.g. SELECT ISNULL([OnCall], 'default') AS [OnCall], ... Anyone with a better idea please let me know, thanks!

Comment: That's not a hack, that's the correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment it sounds like you found a solution.  I am only answering this to provide a suggestion based on the fact you are pivoting so many columns and they are all hard-coded. You can use dynamic SQL for a PIVOT and your query would look something like this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @colsPivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Name) 
                    from dbo.LookupAssociations
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT distinct ', IsNull(' + QUOTENAME(Name) +', ''Default'')'
                    from dbo.LookupAssociations
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT Bizname, ' + @colsPivot + ' from 
            (
                SELECT s.Biz_Name, la.Name AS Association, ISNULL(i.Location, ''Default'') as Location
                FROM  dbo.ShopAssociations sa 
                INNER JOIN dbo.LookupAssociations la 
                    ON sa.AssociationID = la.AssociationID 
                RIGHT JOIN dbo.Basic_Shop_Info s 
                    ON sa.ShopID = s.ShopID 
                INNER JOIN dbo.Images i 
                    ON la.ImageID = i.ImageID
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                min(Location)
                for association in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p 
            '

execute(@query)
```

The value `@colsPivot` is adding the `IsNull()` around each of you columns so you can put in place the `Default` value. But this should provide the same result as your original query where everything was hard-coded.

This will get the list of columns at run-time so then you do not have to hard-code anything and it will accept new values without having to change the query.

Answer (score 0):

I got this:

```
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(c.col+cast(rn as varchar(10))) 
                    from 
                    (
                      select row_number() over(partition by person_nbr 
                                               order by person_nbr,first_name,        last_name, medication_name) rn
                      from TA_PIVOT
                    ) d
                    cross apply
                    (
                      select 'diag' col, 1 sort
                    ) c
                    group by col, rn, sort
                    order by rn, sort
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

    set @query = 'SELECT person_nbr, first_name, last_name,medication_name,' + @cols + '
              from
              (
                select person_nbr,first_name,last_name,medication_name,
                  col+cast(rn as varchar(10)) col,
                  value
                from
                (
                 -- when you perform an unpivot the datatypes have to be the same. 
                 -- you might have to cast the datatypes in this query
                  select person_nbr,first_name,last_name, medication_name,   cast(icd_code_id as varchar(500)) diag,
                    row_number() over(partition by person_nbr order by person_nbr,   first_name, last_name,medication_name) rn
                  from ta_pivot
                ) src
                unpivot
                (
                  value
                  for col in (diag)
                ) unpiv
              ) d
              pivot 
              (
                  max(value)
                  for col in (' + @cols + ')
              ) p '

    execute(@query);
```